# Adapt html5 file uploader to use known file URL instead?

Tags: html, file, url, upload

I am trying to adapt an html5 file uploader (from tutorial) so it can submit an image URL (already held in a javascript variable) instead of asking the user to browse for a local file.

I believe the relevant code to adapt (but I might be wrong) is:

```
  <input type="file" name="image_file" id="image_file" onclick=""   onchange="fileSelectHandler()" />
```

Taken from tutorial: http://www.script-tutorials.com/html5-image-uploader-with-jcrop/

My end process will be:

1. Browse facebook albums and obtain gallery image to javascript variable (jquery.getfacebookalbums.js) - PASS (I can already Alert the URL of chosen file)
2. Adapt the HTML5 file uploader as used in the tutorial, to push the stored facebook image URL instead of a file.  (And it would be ideal to be able to do this without redundant  button clicks, since file url is already present to input)

Many thanks!

UPDATE:

My attempts at a starting point to achieve this have failed.

In my main html page I have a javascript variable storing full path to .jpg

The original post sequence was:

(html file)

(.js file)
function fileSelectHandler() {

```
// get selected file
var oFile = $('#image_file')[0].files[0];
```

...

And variations I've tried to post a stored javascript variable .jpg URL are:

(html file javascript)

```
alert("image_file is" +  image_file);
fileSelectHandler();
```

or

```
     <form action="fileSelectHandler()">
  URL: <input type="text" name="image_file" id="image_file" value="splashScreen.jpg">

  <input type="submit" value="Submit form">
</form>
```

As starting points.

...And I would like to be able to Alert from the fileSelectHandler() in the .js file as to what value it has received for:   var oFile = $('#image_file')[0].files[0];    so I can more easily understand what is being passed - but alert(oFile)  or alert($('#image_file')) is being ignored.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Throw the HTML 5 file uploader out completely. Use JS to add a input (hidden or text) with the URL as the value to the form.

Comment: Hi Quentin, my first attempts at passing this variable to the .js function have not been successful. Could you help highlight what I'm doing wrong? Many thanks!